# solving integral $\int{{3^x}{e^x}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am helping my teenager son. So far I have been able to answer all his questions, and to solve all the problems he has had problems with. Except this one.

$\int{{3^x}{e^x}dx}$

Please, help me keep my success track and my son's confidence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: try rewriting $3^x$ as $e^{x \ln 3}$.

Comment: I see! (why didn't see it before, it's been two days of having this in my mind) thank you very much!

Comment: @PA01: Even without knowing this identity, there are ways. Did you try integration by parts?

Comment: yes I did, I tried both u=e^x and v=e^x . To my despair, both lead me to integrals of similar type e^x k^x. I had obviously overlooked some basic exponential techniques.

Comment: @PA01: Leading to the same can sometimes be a bonus! 

If $\displaystyle I = \int 3^x e^x \text{dx}$

then,

$\displaystyle I = \int 3^x \dfrac{d(e^x)}{dx}  \text{dx} = 3^x e^x - \int \dfrac{d (3^x)}{dx} e^x \text{dx} = 3^x e^x - \log 3 \int 3^x e^x \text{dx}$

Thus

$\displaystyle  I = 3^x e^x - \log 3 \times I$

Hence

$\displaystyle  I = \dfrac{3^x e^x}{1 + \log 3} + \text{constant}$

Comment: I remember a similar trick being used for integrals of exp(ax)sin(bx) because differentiating the sine twice brings you back.

Comment: @Ross: I presume you've seen this [previous thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7986)...

Comment: @J.M.:  I had forgotten it.  Thanks

Comment: @moron thanks! didnt realize this truth. +1

Answer (score 8):

Why not simply $\int 3^x e^x \mathrm dx = \int (3e)^x \mathrm dx = \frac{(3e)^x}{\ln(3e)} + Constant$

To see that $\int (3e)^x \mathrm dx = \frac{(3e)^x}{\ln(3e)}+C$,  You can differentiate $(3e)^x$ i.e. Let

$$y = (3e)^x$$

$$\ln y = x \ln(3e)$$

$$ \mathrm dy/\mathrm dx = y \ln(3e) = (3e)^x \ln(3e)$$

Comment: Can you explain why it is not? I do not get it. I must be overlooking something easy

Comment: Sorry, I was sleepy as I wrote that one. You are right. (I deleted the erroneous comment.)

Comment: @J.M., deleting a comment on which other comments depend leads, more often than not, to more confusion instead of less. Because now picakhu's comment (and any further comment) is erroneous.