# What is u-substitution?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

In answers on this site often the word "u-substitution" appears. Why this is called u-substitution? Is it the same as integration by substitution?

(I never heard this term before and I'm not sure if we have it in my native language)

*Edit:* I myself find the question rather stupid. However, I constantly was thinking "maybe I'm missing something". From the comments I can see that I'm not the only one who gets confused if something simple like "integration by substitution" is called something else like "u-substitution". Especially, if there is "u-substitution" maybe there is "v-substitution" and "t-substitution", and ... . All things which I might never heard of.

So I guess I leave this question here for everybody else who does not know what u-substitution is.

Comment: It seems to be American slang; [I remember being confused by it too](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7986)...

Comment: This question is answered by the last sentence of the introduction to the Wikipedia article, which is the third Google result (for me) for "u-substitution": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Comment: @J.M. mathematics slang? Nice :) Soon we'll be calling $C^{\infty}$ functions "smoothies" and prime numbers "lil' ninjas"

Comment: "Smoothies" I can understand, but why "lil' ninjas"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's because the letter $u$ is often used, for some reason, to denote the name of the function that is used in the substitution.

**edit** and indeed, as Qiaochu Yuan mentioned, we're talking about integration by substitution.

Comment: And it is the same as integrate by substitution?

Comment: @Fabian: yes, it is.