# How to integrate e to the power to the power?

Tags: integration

How should I integrate?

$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^{1/3}}dx$

I think this is a simple question for the experts.  But a bit hard to tell Google what I want.  So, thanks for your help!  :)

And [this](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=e%5Ex%5E%281%2F3%29&random=false) looks terrifying to me.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Try the change of variable $u=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ (so $dx=3u^2du$).

Comment: Incidentally, [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%28-x%5E%281%2F3%29%29%2C+x%3D0..infty) is (IMO) more convenient to use.

Comment: wow, haven't done these since Freshman college, U-substitution?  thanks for the hint.  Still trying to remember why we do that.

Comment: I was googling for that site, there it is!

Comment: What do you mean by "U- substitution"? The reason for doing a change of variables like this is simply "the bit in the exponent looks tricky, let's simplify it by defining it to just be something new, like $u$".

Comment: wait, it's not u-sub?  can you link to me where this technique is from?

Comment: @Sharkos, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37793).

Comment: lol, I see. Thanks J. M.